# node-gyp rebuild - Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, centos6.5

I'm getting an error while doing node-gyp rebuild on CentOS 6.8:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 295, in LoadBuildFileIncludesIntoDict
    LoadOneBuildFile(include, data, aux_data, None, False, check),
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 238, in LoadOneBuildFile
    None)
  File "/usr/local/app/jenkins/.node-gyp/iojs-1.4.0/common.gypi", line 1
    {
```

---

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    gyp ERR! configure error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:355:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--target=1.4.0" "--arch=x64" "--target_platform=linux" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.4-linux-x64"
    gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/app/jenkins/workspace/offline/desktop/deploy/node_modules/sqlite3
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
    gyp ERR! not ok
```

Try with updating node-gyp, globally installing node-gyp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

updated python version to `Python 2.7.6`

issue fixed.

Comment: how to install pythong 2.7.6 https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get second answer and change the wget link to https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't use upgraded python for versioning reasons, try changing cli. Powershell as admin worked when git bash and command prompt both failed.

Comment: I was using iTerm that gave the issue. Switching to terminal fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this issue for quite long on `macOS`. For me, on macOS, I had to

1. Install Python 2.7.x while Python 3 was already installed
2. Ensure Python 2 path was included in $PATH
3. Switch CLI. It didn't work in iTerm2, but worked fine on standard macOS terminal

I did install `xcode` as well, but that didn't have an effect