# ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic4, node-gyp

Issues with my MAC forced me to have to format and start fresh.  I uploaded my project to GITHUB and downloaded it after installing NPM 6.9.0 & Node 12.6.0.  Nothing works and i keep getting this gyp error:

```js
gyp: Call to 'node findJavaHome.js' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.6/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.11.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point...I've tried all of the suggestions I've seen online:

```js
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm
sudo node-gyp rebuild -g --unsafe-perm
sudo chmod 777
sudo node-gyp rebuild -g --unsafe-perm
sudo npm config set unsafe-perm=true
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate at this point.  Again, I had to format in order to upgrade my MAC os Mojave 10.14.5

I've never had to constantly use sudo with NPM in the past so I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node-gyp rebuild - Error: \`gyp\` failed with exit code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598906/node-gyp-rebuild-error-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was updating the `node-sass` version (I was getting this error while installing node package manager packages for Angular) from `4.9.3` to `4.13.1`